# Is it possible to merge properties of same selectors from different partial files in sass?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Let's assume you have a style.scss file as well as two partials called _base.scss and _typo.scss.

style.scss only contains:

```
@import 'compass', 'x1', 'x2';
```

_base.scss contains:

```
p{
    width:80%;
}
```

_typo.scss contains:

```
p{
    color:red;
}
```

when the style.scss is compiled style.css looks like:

```
p {
 width: 80%;
}

p {
 color: red;
}
```

instead of merging the properties of the same selector into one in the final css that it would look like that:

```
p {
 width: 80%;
 color: red;
}
```

is it possible to get the latter result somehow? or is there anything not recommendable about it? best regards ralf

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a good idea - if you just put rules together that have matching selectors you miss out on ordering. For insance, if there was another rule for the colour of #foo which was also a paragraph, then depending on where it appeared in the CSS order, doing something like this would produce unpredictable results.

Comment: @moopet  that sounds like a reasonable objection.thanks!

Comment: @cimmanon  yes i considered it already. it looks odd to do something like:   p {@extend p; color:red;} and so far i thought it would error in general, but  i gave it a try and it at least compiled. but unfortunately same effect. one p from each partial scss file is still returned.